# Reference to left hand side on implicit cast operator

Tags: c#, operators, implicit-conversion

Is there a way I can get an instance of the left hand side of the operation when overloading an implicit cast from int to `A`?

Like this:

```
public class A
{
    int myInt;
    public static implicit operator A(int x)
    {
        a.myInt = x;
    }
}
```

and then

```
A myA = new A();
myA = 2;
```

so that `myA.myInt` is `2`

I searched on the internet but I couldn't find an answer to this exact problem. I don't think it is possible since it is a static function and it will throw you an error if you try to put two parameters into the function. Also, I can see this would give you an error if you tried to do this on a null variable (like if I had declared it like this `A myA;`). But then you could do it in a struct (because as far as I know structs can't ever be null - or can't be assigned null -, please correct me if I'm wrong).

I'm just wondering if there is some sort of wizardry that I could do to make something like this work.

Comment: It is like saying when I do `(MyDestType)myExpr` there should be a reference to "the" `MyDestType`. But there __is no__ `MyDestType` before the cast has occurred. In your conversion operator body, first create an instance as a local variable. Then you can modify it if needed, Finally return it. What you have above, is not legal C#.

Comment: What if I overloaded the = operator? is there a way to get a reference to the left hand side of the operation?

Comment: @ItsaMeTuni You can't overload that operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get a reference to `myA.myInt` or any other left side, because it is not always there.

Here is an example when determining the left side would be problematic:

```
void Foo(A a) {...}
...
Foo(2);
```

Above, calling `Foo(2)` requires invoking your implicit conversion operator, yet its return value is not assigned to anything other than `Foo`'s `a` parameter, which is not a variable that would be available in the caller.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/3oKeFL)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.  The implicit operator returns a value.  It is the code generated by the C# compiler that calls that code to get the value and use it in whatever way the caller indicates it should be used.

It's worth noting that there may not even *be* a storage location.  If someone writes `SomeMethodThatAcceptsAnAInstance(2)` then you're not storing the results of the implicit conversion in a variable.  You could also write `A a = 2;` in which `a` is an uninitialized variable until the implicit operator's value is set to it, so the storage location does not have valid state at the time the implicit operator is called.